# ExpressionEngine Search: Get exact match from channel field

Tags: php, mysql, search, expressionengine

I have two entries/reviews for a location/entry with an id of 13. However, I can not get an exact match so EE returns anything with a 13 ie 134 etc.

I have tried where="exact" with no success.

Example:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="reviews" dynamic="no" search:reviewed_business="13" parse="inward"}
<?php $reviews++; ?>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

$reviews should == 2 but returns 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, Precede the search term with an "=" like so...

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="reviews" dynamic="no" search:reviewed_business="=13" parse="inward"}
<?php $reviews++; ?>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

[Expression Engine Documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name)

Enjoy!